# Using Polymer with WAMP

Tags: php, polymer

I have been working in an online environment on a Polymer based project. Right now I am tasked with trying to run the polymer project on my local machine (Windows 10).

When using polymer, I run polymer serve --open, I get a not found error with a url of `http://localhost:8080/components/wc/`. wc is my project folder that I am running the command on, so when I switch to `http://localhost:8080/wc/` or `http://localhost:8080/wc/index.php` , I still seem to get a not found error.

Am I doing this correctly? As an alternative, how would I go about setting this up in WAMP? Would I just drag my folder into a directory in wamp, then run the server?